The difference between an adjective and a noun


He is the richest.


Is the 'richest' functioning as a noun or not?

Yᴏᴜʀ Qᴜᴇꜱᴛɪᴏɴꜱ Aʀᴇ Tᴏᴏ Sʜᴏʀᴛ: please put more effort into composing your questions, as it is unfair to expect others to put more effort into answering than you have put into asking. Tell us what led you to ask the question, such as some confusion or lack of clarity over some particular theory or model, what you think the answer may be, or why you question there even being a clear answer. What research into this matter did you do and where, and what in particular did you find there that seems unclear or conflicting to you? What is your own guess or guesses, and why do you think so?

No, it is not. There is a noun or noun phrase that has been omitted. The richest person, or something like that.

No, although "the richest" functions as a noun phrase.
In your example "richest" is a substantive - an adjective used as a noun.
Compare
"The deaf are at a disadvantage, the poor are starving and the blind are all beggars and yet the richest live in luxury."
Substantives differ from common nouns as they are uncountable but, unlike uncountable nouns, they take a plural verb concordance; they must be qualified by a determiner, but the determiners are limited. The definite article (or occasionally a possessive) is commonest.

You need to add a reference for your chosen definition of substantive, and point out that there are other definitions in use (see Collins; Nordquist).
